# Use google embed maps in angular with dynamic src-attribute

Tags: angular, google-maps

I'm using angular (6) and I'm writing a re-usable component to display an embedded google map. Main reasons are:

- The location is fixed, so the link is stored in the database
- API limits are higher with google embedded map api compared to google map api.

There is one pitfall in using embedded map api being the usage of an iFrame. Due to security reasons (xss), it's a bit more difficult to implement. Although I'm using Angulars DomSanitizer, I still struggle assigning the source variable.

Replacing the dynamic reference with a static one works, changing [src] to src in the iFrame give me a routing error..

**Angular component**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-google-map-embed',
      templateUrl: './google-map-embed.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./google-map-embed.component.css']
    })
    export class GoogleMapEmbedComponent implements OnInit {

      private placeUri:string = "";
      private key:String = "My_Key"
      @Input() type:string = "";

      constructor(public sanitizer:DomSanitizer) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.type);
        switch(this.type){
          case 'place':
            this.placeUri = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=" + this.key +
              "&q=Fairmont+Empress,Victoria+BC&attribution_source=Google+Maps+Embed+API&attribution_web_url=http://www.fairmont.com/empress-victoria/&attribution_ios_deep_link_id=comgooglemaps://?daddr=Fairmont+Empress,+Victoria,+BC";
            break;
          case 'directions':
            this.placeUri = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions\
                              ?key=YOUR_API_KEY\
                              &origin=Oslo+Norway\
                              &destination=Telemark+Norway\
                              &avoid=tolls|highways"
        }
      }

      mapsURL() {
        console.log(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.placeUri));
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.placeUri);
      }

    }
```

**Angular template**

```
    <p>Generated URL for debugging purposes: {{placeUri}}</p>

    <iframe
      width="600"
      height="450"
      frameborder="0" style="border:0"

      [src]="mapsURL()" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

**App-component.html**

```
    <app-google-map-embed type='place'></app-google-map-embed>
```

References of API's:
DomSanitizer: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer
Google embedded map API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide
Google map API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map